# Multiple times validator calls for dynamically added content using unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

This is classic problem, that when you add content to the FORM by javascript this content is not validated despite you call 
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");

Ok, here is nice solution: just clean information before parse:

```
$("form").removeData("validator");
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");`
```

That's quite nice, and really seems working. BUT!
Each validator is called as many times as you call this block:

```
$("form").removeData("validator");
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```

You can check this case easily by creating custom validator and setting breakpoint inside or any debug output:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checksalary",
   function (value, element, param) {
   return (!isNaN(value) && parseInt(value) > 0) || $("#" + param).attr('checked');
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add
("checksalary", ["param"], function (options) {
  options.rules["checksalary"] = options.params.param;
  options.messages["checksalary"] = options.message;
});
```

That's looks really non-professional if your validators called few times instead of one.

**Is there any other information should be cleaned before calling parse()?**

And let's assume you've called parse() 100 times. I think such overhead will be clearly visible by client.

**UPDATE**
Ok, I could debug tonns of scripts, and found, that even if we clean validation information for the form, we still not cleaned this bind, caused by line 53 in jquery.validate.js

```
    this.submit(function (event) {
        if (validator.settings.debug)
        // prevent form submit to be able to see console output
            event.preventDefault();
...
```

So I've created temporary ugly fix for this case, which works for now, but I believe there should be better way around, like update validation object, and not to create new one:

```
    var validator = $.data(this[0], 'validator');
    var skipReAttach = false;
    if (validator) {
        //return validator;
        skipReAttach = true;
    }

    validator = new $.validator(options, this[0]);
    $.data(this[0], 'validator', validator);

    if (validator.settings.onsubmit) {

        // allow suppresing validation by adding a cancel class to the submit button
        this.find("input, button").filter(".cancel").click(function () {
            validator.cancelSubmit = true;
        });

        // when a submitHandler is used, capture the submitting button
        if (validator.settings.submitHandler) {
            this.find("input, button").filter(":submit").click(function () {
                validator.submitButton = this;
            });
        }

        // validate the form on submit
        if (skipReAttach)
            return validator;

        this.submit(function (event) {
            if (validator.settings.debug)
            // prevent form submit to be able to see console output
                event.preventDefault();
```

For sure - now only 
    `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");`
should be called.

**But what is the good way to fix this problem?**

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read allot here but I don't see a question ?

Comment: Hi. I've asked question how to avoid multiple call of validators. And found solution by myself.
But general problem was not solved and therefore I've modified my message to be more "questive".

Answer (score 1):

I have found a not so elegant solution using a lot of help from [this solution](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/).  Works well for me so far, though it has not be thoroughly tested.

Instead of using:

```
$("form").removeData("validator"); 
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation"); 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```

Use the code below:

```
function resetValidationAttributes(parentContainer) {
    $(parentContainer).find(':input[data-val = true]').each(function() {
        //
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement(this, true);

        var form = $(this).first().closest('form');

        var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data('unobtrusiveValidation');
        var validator = form.validate();

        $.each (unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
            if (validator.settings.rules[ elname] == undefined) {
                var args = {};
                $.extend(args, elrules);
                args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
                $('[name="' + elname + '"]').rules("add" , args );
            } else {
                $.each(elrules, function(rulename, data) {
                    if(validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
                        var args = {};
                        args[rulename ] = data;
                        args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
                        $('[name="' + elname + '"]').rules("add", args);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It takes the container that the dynamic content was loaded into, and then searches for any inputs in that container.  For each input, it calls parseElement with true specified in the function call (Look at the unobtrusive validation file for more info on that).  Lastly, it goes through the validators on the form and adds the field to the rules if its not there.